# Is there a category of ducted HVAC/IAQ parts but sized for what is typical for ductless systems?

Tags: hvac, humidifier, mini-split, dehumidifier, air-filter

There's old houses with extensive remodels that are in need of some kind of "zoned" help in interior air quality (or "IAQ", I'm not sure how common this acronym is just yet), likely in large part because there's parts of the house that are tight as a drum from the remodel but still lacking in this on the older parts of the house.  This looks like a DIY project but I'm having trouble finding parts typical in size (as in square foot, humidity, air flow, etc.) to what is seen in ductless systems but the situation calls for running ducts to and from different parts of the house.  Is there a name for this category of HVAC and IAQ systems?  Or am I just going to have to make the best of what I found?

This isn't the only situation that I'm trying to solve but is representative enough to set the scene.  In the kitchen there is often plenty of heat and humidity, as well as some soot and other particulates, from natural gas appliances and cooking of food.  Elsewhere in the same house, bedrooms mostly, there's often a lack of heat and humidity.  I'm looking to build an IAQ system that pulls air from the kitchen, filters it, adds or removes humidity per user settings, if it somehow aids in the humidity control and/or adds little to the cost then do some heating or cooling, then dumps that air into the bedrooms.  The thermostat for the central heating, cooling, and humidifier is in the kitchen, the IAQ control would then be in one of the bedrooms or in the adjacent hallway.

As this IAQ system is to perform four functions I would assume I need to assemble four parts.  The filtration would be done by a filter, but the filter itself is consumable so the real thing I need is the name of the part that holds the filter in place.  From what I'm seeing so far this must be part of the air circulation device or is intended to be constructed to fit the location as part of the duct work.  If there's a part that holds the filter in place then it must have a name, right?  If this is simply part of the air cirulation device then this may be a moot point.  The intent is to find something for the IAQ system that uses the same filter size as the central HVAC for convenience, but I suspect I may just have to take what I can get.

What I see for the names of the air circulation device is "air handler unit" or just "AHU", "furnace", or some variation on "duct fan".  I don't believe I want an AHU as that looks to be something that is for heat pumps and air conditioners.  Being as I'm looking to dehumidify, that heat pumps and air conditioners dehumidify as a function of cooling, then do I want an AHU?  My guess is that I could intentionally under-size the condenser so I get more de-humidification than cooling but that looks like a hack.

I know from experience that having a furnace at the center of this IAQ system would work but I don't want to take on anything I can't DIY myself.  I'd want a very small furnace if that's what I end up doing.  If there's electrical requirement above a 30 amp 240VAC circuit, or there's a fuel gas connection any more complicated than threading it to a propane tank, then I'm calling in a professional.

A ducted fan might work but then I'd really need to know a simple means to mount a filter into place.  Are there options beyond AHU, furnace, or ducted fan that I'm missing?  Are there alternative names I might need to use in searching for any of these options?

When it comes to humidifiers and dehumidifiers that connect to ductwork it looks like they are called "inline" or "whole house".  Is there another term I should be looking for?  What of using some kind of air conditioning for dehumidifying?  Are there tables or charts that could guide me on converting my de-humidification needs into tons of air conditioning power?

Comment: From my read you're trying to describe solutions rather than your goals, which makes it tougher to answer. How would you summarize what you are trying to accomplish in one paragraph, finishing it with a single question?

Comment: Rewritten to hopefully clarify the questions.  I have a plan on the solution but I'm confused on what the parts are called.  In a central HVAC system there's a "sun" upon which the "planets" orbit.  The "sun" being a furnace or AHU for heating, cooling, filtration, and air circulation.  Then the "planets" being the humidifier, dehumidifier, and/or ventilation.  As I don't need heating or cooling the "sun" may end up being something different, especially given the humidity control is primarily for a portion of the house.

Comment: I think it's still too broad for the way this site is designed. Overall it sounds like either you're looking for a ducted heat pump with a dehumidifier, humidifier, and filter box. That's all very normal stuff. If you're trying to do it distributed throughout the house, well, good luck - you're either going to be in to territory usually handled by expensive commercial systems, or you'll be doing a lot of DIY.

Comment: @KMJ "you'll be doing a lot of DIY"  That's fine, I want to avoid having to call professionals if possible.  After some poking around I believe the term I'm looking for is "independent duct".  That's not a category of size but application.  It is "independent" by not being part of the central HVAC duct work.

Comment: By DIY I there I mean you'll be building things from scratch. It sounds sort of like you're describing a VRF system, but nobody installs those in houses unless they're huge mansions. I'm still not entirely sure what your goal is.

Comment: @KMJ "It sounds sort of like you're describing a VRF system"  No, a VRF system runs coolant lines to the different rooms or floors, I want to move ***air*** between rooms or floors. If the top floor is hot and dry and the basement cool and damp then I want to pull air directly from the basement to the top floor, not run the central fan because the middle floor is fine on temp and RH.  Since the primary function is humidity control then it could be called IAQ rather than HVAC, or that's what I'm lead to believe. I know what I need but without proper names for them it is difficult to order them.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is move heat around, I think you're finding it difficult to locate these systems because it's a problem people solve using other means instead of moving air. VRF systems move the heat around between rooms via that coolant. Humidity is rarely controlled precisely in residential or commercial environments. It tends to be controlled in labs and data centers, again using VRFs or area air handlers that can humidify and dehumidfy.

Comment: @KMJ "If what you're trying to do is move heat around..."  I'm trying to move *humidity* around.  Warm or cool air would move with the humidity but that may be beneficial, and if this is a problem then there's simple fixes for that. In one house the basement is nearly always too damp, to the point mold could be a problem, and the bedrooms nearly always too dry, to the point of dry air nosebleeds.  There's a straight shot up the middle of the house (likely where the old chimney used to be) for an air duct.  The solution appears obvious, finding the parts is just a matter of knowing their names.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get that simple one-liner from your long question, with all the distractors embedded in it. If you just want to move humid air, it sounds like you want to ventilate. That's  a ventilator fan or in-line fan plus a humidistat. Maybe add a filter box if you want to filter the air as it heads from one place to the other. Panasonic makes really nice fans of this style, listed as remote bathroom fans.

Answer (score 1):

You don't run ducts for ductless systems. You run heat-transfer-fluid lines to wall (or, rarely, ceiling) units in the rooms you want to heat or cool directly.

At most, if you're trying to economize, you might do something to improve airflow between a room which has one of these units and an adjacent room that doesn't.

Comment: "*You don't run ducts for ductless systems.*"  I understand that.  "*You run heat-transfer-fluid lines to wall (or, rarely, ceiling) units in the rooms you want to heat or cool directly.*"  Heating and cooling is a secondary/optional concern, the primary issue is humidity control and air filtration.  Ductless systems do little to nothing for humidity control, filtration, or circulation, I'd have to run ducts for that.

Comment: "*At most, if you're trying to economize, you might do something to improve airflow between a room which has one of these units and an adjacent room that doesn't.*"  That is the concern but as I'm trying to make clear in the question is that ducted HVAC parts come sized for heating and cooling an entire house, not to manage humidity between floors, or a few rooms on the same floor.  I'm running into a nomenclature problem, I'm trying to ask for what I need without knowing the proper terms as a starting point.

Comment: Ductless can dehumidify, but you're right about the others not being covered. However, if those are your concerns -- if you're going to run ductwork anyway -- you may be better off looking at something like the mini-duct central systems. Those too can be equipped with heat pumps; in fact, those can use ground-sourced heat pumps rather than air-sourced and kick heating and cooling efficiency up even further. But new ducts are a pain to retrofit into older houses; I had zero interest in that approach .

Comment: In running a search on "mini duct" I find what I believe you are referring too.  The problem with that term is "ductless mini-split" also contains the words "mini" and "duct".  An alternative name appears to be "high velocity", and that should narrow the results.  This may be at least a half of a solution, they will filter and circulate the air, and will dehumidify some as an artifact of cooling.  Running "regular velocity" duct work is not an issue in this case, the walls will be opened up wide for wiring and insulation.  Because of the speed of the airflow humidifying may not be an option.

Comment: Yes, the high velocity systems are what I was thinking of. If you are willing and able to deal with ductwork -- and with the quirks of a central system vs. the quirks of a distributed system -- that looks like a good alternative. For me, in a house I am _not_ doing a major rehab on, that simply wasn't an option; minisplit was the only way I was going to install whole-house AC and heat-pump heating came along for free.